# php var_dump() does not show non-english character

Tags: php, utf-8

I am now working on Japanese projects. When I use var_dump() the japanese characters are not show correctly in browser. But English characters are showing correctly. How can I fix this problem. The following is portion of my var_dump() result,

```
  'id' => int 71680
  'customer_id' => int 16161
  'amount' => string '1' (length=1)
  'second_customer_id' => null
  'second_amount' => null
  'customer_name' => string 'é£›çŸ¥å’Œã€€å•“ä¸€' (length=18)
  'second_customer_name' => null
  'payment_flag' => string 'æŽ›' (length=3)
  'payment_flag_id' => int 2
  'order_id' => int 9108
  'article_name' => string 'ç¥­å£‡' (length=6)
  'article_id' => int 1000001
  'sales_price' => string '200000.0' (length=8)
  'discount' => int 0
  'ceremony_cooking_category_id' => null
  'payment_date' => string '2014/12/05' (length=10)
  'payment_hour' => string '0' (length=1)
  'payment_min' => string '0' (length=1)
  'hall_id' => null
  'hall_name' => null
  'hall_address' => null
  'hall_tel' => null
  'stock_date' => null
  'stock_confirm_emps_name' => null
  'check_date' => null
  'check_emps_name' => null
  'note' => string 'memo 333' (length=8)
  'label' => string 'label 333' (length=9)
```

Comment: can you post your head here as well, if you are confuse you need to tell hi to use utf-8, if you are not doing that it will a problem

Comment: @user2860957 What do you mean head? Do you mean html head tag?
Will you please explain me?

Comment: i might be wrong, as var dump dont return an thing, but i am thinking using head and telling it use utf-8 can help you, and yah i mean html head some thing like `<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>`

Comment: i checked it on my end, is fine, are you returning these values from database??

Comment: @user2860957 Yes, those values are from database.

Comment: read this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php, in short you have to use mysqli set charset, but read the link, as it may 100 reason, so its better you read the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
Header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf8");
```

before your `var_dump`, change `utf8` to the encoding your database use.

Answer (score 1):

use `Content-Type: text/plain` and `charset=utf-8`, this force the output to render as plain text.

add this line before outputting anything.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Reference : [Charset W3](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index)